# Error al tratar de mostrar un cuadro de confirmación para elementos dentro de grid HTML con Javascript y Flask (Python)

Tags: javascript, html, python, css, flask

Actualmente esta es la estructura que forma el grid de elementos de una base de datos, está realizado con un backend en flask, por eso el for hecho de esa manera

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/admin.css">
</head>

<body>
    
    <main class="principal">

        <div class="item-grid">

            {% for usuario in usuarios %}

            <div class="item">
                <div class="nombre"> {{usuario[0]}} {{usuario[1]}} </div>
                <div class="correo">Correo: {{usuario[2]}} </div>
                <div class="genero">Genero: {{usuario[3]}} </div>
                <div class="area-botones">
                    <button class="boton editar">Editar</button>
                    <button class="boton eliminar">Eliminar</button>

                    <!-- Si se presiona el botón eliminar, se visualiza confirmacion-eliminar  -->

                    <div class="confirmacion-eliminar">
                        <div class="container-confirma">
                            <div>¿Seguro que desea eliminar al usuario {{usuario[0]}} {{usuario[1]}}?</div>
                            <div class="botones-confirma">
                                <button class="boton confirmar">Confirmar</button>
                                <button class="boton cancelar">Cancelar</button>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

            {% endfor %}

        </div>
    </main>

</body>

</html>
```

Justo antes de terminar el body, tengo este código de javascript

```
<script>
    
    const botonesEliminar = document.querySelectorAll('.eliminar');

    botonesEliminar.forEach(boton => {
        boton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            
            const confirmacion = boton.closest('.item').querySelector('.confirmacion-eliminar');
            
            confirmacion.classList.toggle('active');
        });
    });

    
    const botonesConfirmar = document.querySelectorAll('.confirmar');

    botonesConfirmar.forEach(boton => {
        boton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            
            const confirmacion = boton.closest('.item').querySelector('.confirmacion-eliminar');
            confirmacion.classList.remove('active');
        });
    });

    const botonesCancelar = document.querySelectorAll('.cancelar');

    botonesCancelar.forEach(boton => {
        boton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            const confirmacion = boton.closest('.item').querySelector('.confirmacion-eliminar');
            confirmacion.classList.remove('active');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Y este es el CSS de "confirmacion-eliminar":

```
.confirmacion-eliminar {
position: fixed;
background-color: rgb(171, 171, 171);
z-index: 100;
top: 40vh;
left: 75vh;
user-select: none;
opacity: 0;
```

}

```
.confirmacion-eliminar.active {
opacity: 1;
```

}

El grid se muestra correctamente en la página y cuando hago click en "eliminar" también, sin embargo, estoy teniendo problemas cada vez que trato de cerrar este "popup" de confirmación ya que por alguna razón solamente se cierra en el último elemento del grid correctamente, para el resto debo de volver a hacer click en el botón "eliminar" cuando debería ser ya sea el boton confirmar o cancelar.

Espero haber sido lo suficientemente claro, agradezco cualquier ayuda :).